# JPA cascade delete for many levels of relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm facing to a problem when implenting a cascade delete in JPA. Given the entities below:

```java
@Entity
class Quiz {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quiz")
    private List<QuizQuestion> questions;
}

@Entity
class QuizQuestion {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question")
    private List<QuizQuestionItem> items;

    @ManyToOne
    private Quiz quiz;
}

@Entity
class QuizQuestionItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question")
    private List<QuizQuestionItemAnswer> answers;

    @ManyToOne
    private QuizQuestion question;
}

@Entity
class QuizQuestionItemAnswer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private QuizQuestionItem question;
}
```

And the requirements is: **Delete a quiz should delete all questions, items and answers related to it**.

I implement a custom repository to handle this requirement like this:

```java
public class DeleteQuizRepositoryImpl implements DeleteQuizRepository {
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public DeleteQuizRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void deleteInDepth(Quiz quiz) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM QuizQuestionItemAnswer ans WHERE ans.question.question.quiz.id = ?1");
        query.setParameter(1, quiz.getId());
        query.executeUpdate();

        query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM QuizQuestionItem item WHERE item.question.quizz.id = ?1");
        query.setParameter(1, quiz.getId());
        query.executeUpdate();

        query = entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM QuizQuestion q WHERE q.quiz.id = ?1");
        query.setParameter(1, quiz.getId());
        query.executeUpdate();

        query = entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM Quiz q WHERE q.id = ?1");
        query.setParameter(1, quiz.getId());
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

This class has a problem when executing on mysql, SQLSyntaxException for generated SQL:

```
delete from quiz_question_item_answers where exists(select 1 from quiz_question_items q1_0 where q1_0.id=quiz_question_item_answers.question_id and q2_0.quiz_id=?)
```

However, in test environment (h2 database), it works fine.

So,

1. why JPA generate the SQL with **q2_0**? (the source of the problem)
2. how to solve and make JPA to generate the right sql?

Comment: Did you consider the recommended way using the cascade and orphanRemoval attributes on your relations (e.g. `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DELETE, orphanRemoval=true`)?

Comment: @Karsten No, but I don't understand why the generated SQL is not  correct.

Comment: What is the query generated in the H2 environment - seems like if it works there but is not working elsewhere, it is a bug. How to solve depends on the issue, but there might be other ways to rewrite the query, such as using an exists subquery yourself, that might bypass the issue. ie "delete from QuizQuestionItemAnswer a where exists (select 1 from QuizQuestionItemAnswer a1 where a1.question.question.quiz.id = ?1 and a1.id = a.id)"

Comment: @Chris Seems a bug unfortunately. Here is the sql generated on test mode: **delete from quiz_question_item_answer where exists(select 1 from quiz_question_item q1_0 join quiz_question q2_0 on q2_0.id=q1_0.question_id where q1_0.id=quiz_question_item_answer.question_id and q2_0.quiz_id=?)**

Comment: Here is the minimal project that I create to reproduce the bug: [github delete cascade](https://github.com/Abreny/quiz-delete-cascade)